# Excel VBA - Paste code works, but needs Values only to match cell formatting

Tags: excel, vba

Below code works but it pastes along with source formatting, whereas I'd like for it to paste Values only to match cell formatting

```
Sub Paste()
'Tools -> References -> Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
'or you will get a "Compile error: user-defined type not defined"
  Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject
  Dim s As String
  DataObj.GetFromClipboard
  s = DataObj.GetText
  Target.Value = s
End Sub
```

For context: I am calling above code from below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Cells.count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("ToClear")) Is Nothing Then 
            Cancel = True
            Call Paste
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `Target`? Assuming it's a `Range` (global maybe?), assigning to its `.Value` shouldn't in theory change the cell formatting. What are you copying?

Comment: Where is the value in the clipboard copied from?

Comment: I use BeforeDoubleClick as a trigger to paste into the cell I double click on.  I copy strings of text, numbers of alphanumeric strings from sources like Outlook email for example.

Comment: If you copy from Outlook, using `DataObject` is not necessary. Then, as stated in the first comment, **using Range.Value** must not copying any format. If not something confidential, try sharing the respective workbook to see what you try doing. Do you use Outlook automation from Excel?

Comment: I added For context: part at end of OP above, hopefully that brings more clarity to the matter. Not using "Outlook automation from Excel", just happen to be copying from Outlook email or other sources like ERP systems, etc. The idea is for pasting to only bring in the value, not formatting from the source and to paste all data into that one cell I am clicking on, sometimes data caries over to the cell below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
Sub PasteCL()

ActiveCell.Value = Clipboard

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**